# add value to input field automatically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

How to add values automatically without add button? Just select value from dropdown and do it again and again to add them to the same input [like on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKd6B.png).

`html`

```
<select name="programs_dropdown" id="programs_dropdown">
<option value="php">php</option>
<option value="jquery">jquery</option>
<option value="html" selected="selected">HTML</option>
</select>

<div id="add">Add</div>

<input type="text" name="programs_input" id="programs_input" />
```

`jquery`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add').click(function() {
        var program = $("#programs_dropdown").val(); //get value of selected option
        var programs = $('#programs_input').val().split(",");
        if (programs[0] == "") {
            programs.pop()
        }

        if ($.inArray(program, programs) == -1) {
            programs.push(program);
        }

        $('#programs_input').val(programs.join(',')); //add to text input
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Don't use `<div>` for a button. Use `<button>` instead.

Comment: @D.Pardal, they add by comma, but how to make automatically without any button? please check updated question.

Comment: That's not what I was talking about. You should replace `<div id="add">Add</div>` by `<button id="add">Add</button>`.

Comment: @D.Pardal I get it and did it, but I need to know how to remove `button` and automatically add them to the same input field. Please assist

Comment: Why are you not just using a multiple select?

Comment: @epascarello, I dont know how to configure `js code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think This is the answer which you are looking for!

`HTML`

```
<select class="my-select-class">
  <option value="One">One</option>
  <option value="Two">Two</option>
  <option value="Three">Three</option>
  <option value="Four">Four</option>
  <option value="Five">Five</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<input type="text" class="my-input-class">
```

`JQuery`

```
var allSelected = [];

$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".my-select-class").on("change", function(){
    let val = $(this).val();
      let index = allSelected.indexOf(val);
      if (index > -1) allSelected.splice(index, 1);
      else allSelected.push(val);
    $(".my-input-class").val(allSelected.join());
  });
});
```

You can play around with `JQuery` `change` event and get the result which you wanted.

Comment: yes, but add elements to the same field where they are

Comment: I've created a codepen here -> https://codepen.io/rakesh-dl/pen/MWaLEgB
try this, maybe u can use multiselect option and get the result in the same place

Comment: Or maybe advanced, you cna try this https://select2.org/ Use multiselct feature here, You ccan get the result you wanted.

Comment: Method 1 is the most closest, but I need to set element in the same input from which I can select them. Shortly, there need to have one form on page, nothing else

Comment: select2 is not appropriate decision for my case. I tried it

Comment: Then try https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ "Chosen", this is also pretty good.

Comment: I noted your answer as correct. Could you please check another one? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61972742/error-of-getting-value-from-file-html-flask)

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the `.change()` function in jQuery to fire your function whenever changes are made to your `<select>` element. You could then fetch the `.val()` from that and store it into a variable. You can then `append()` an input field with the value that you just stored to a container. Note that you will also need to use concatenation, as you will be exiting your string parameter for the append function to concatenate your drop down value. Concatenation in JavaScript is done by the use of `+`.

Example of concatenation in use that you will need:

```
$("#inputContainer").append("<input type='text' value='"+selectValue+"' /><br />");
```

Full example code to your question:

```js
$( "#programs_dropdown" ).change(function() {
 var selectValue = $(this).val();
  if(selectValue != "default"){
   $("#inputContainer").append("<input type='text' value='"+selectValue+"' /><br />");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="programs_dropdown" id="programs_dropdown">
<option value="default" selected="selected">select value</option>
<option value="php">php</option>
<option value="jquery">jquery</option>
<option value="html">HTML</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<div id="inputContainer"></div>
```

Comment: I have removed `#add` from `button` and added to every `option` tag, but then I can add only one element.

Comment: I see what you mean now, you want to `append()` input fields with your selected value from the dropdown menu. Give me a few.

Comment: Check the edited answer if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: no, could you please check the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61972742/error-of-getting-value-from-file-html-flask)

Comment: I don't understand, did you ask a specific question for one thing, but was actually looking for another? The link you provided seems to be for another thing entirely.

Comment: I can add value automaticaly to the same field using `choose.js`, but there are some problems described in another question